What is the result of #if MACRO and MACRO is defined without value?
If I defined a macro:
#define FOO

And in the code I check it like:
#if FOO
//1
#else
//2
#endif

Which branch will it go? Will the result be different by different compilers? What is the FOO value in the #if FOO?

It will not compile: demo.

@wohlstad, I think that's not always true. My code is compiled for iOS, so it's basically compiler-dependent.

This might be. But gcc and clang are usually quite good representatives for compiling C code. Anyway - you can try in your environment and tell us what was the result.

@wohlstad Mine suggests that it treats the empty macro as non-zero and goes into that branch, which makes me really confused. I'm expecting it should not compile or treat it like zero, but apparently, it doesn't. The compiler is Apple Clang.

@RockingDice Are you defining macro in source as in your example, or as a compiler flag? They typically tend to work differently.

@user694733 It's in the Preprocessor Macros in the Xcode project's build settings. What might be those differences?

Symbols without any value defined with compiler switches typically have default value of 1, where as #define directives in the source code don't.

@user694733 I think you explained my case. Thank you!

C17 6.10.1 specifies the syntax for #if as:

# if constant-expression new-line groupopt

Where:

A constant expression is an item for example like 1 (integer constant) or 1+1 (integer constant expression), or a preprocessor token expanding to such.
New line is the end of the #if line.
Group (optional) is whatever you put between #if and #endif etc.

6.10.1 further states that macro expansion inside #if is done as:

After all replacements due to macro expansion and
the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is
converted into a token. The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is
evaluated according to the rules of 6.6.

Meaning that if some token after #if is not a known preprocessor token, it gets replaced with 0. The reference at the end to 6.6 refers to the chapter defining a constant expression.

Conclusion: if FOO is defined and a known pre-processor token, it will get expanded but the macro is empty in this case. The #if will end up missing a constant expression, since that mandatory part of the syntax is not present before the new line. Meaning we get a syntax error - it is invalid C and will not compile without compiler diagnostics getting raised (see What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?).
However, if FOO was unknown either because it was misspelled or missing, or simply because it was defined in another translation unit unknown to the current one, it will get replaced with 0 and the #if will evaluate as false.

Note that defines that are passed to the program using compiler options such as for example gcc -D may have a default value applied to them. For gcc and clang, that value is 1. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

-D name
Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.


Thanks for the details and sources. I think it's the correct answer to my question. However, I discovered that my case is unrelated to this question because the macros are not defined in the code but in the compiler flags. I thought it would be the same, but not, which @user694733 mentioned in the comments.

@RockingDice I added a note about that scenario at the end.

FYI (you could possibly add to the answer), the specific rule that says #if by itself must produce a diagnostic is C 2018 5.1.1.3 1: “A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint,…”

@EricPostpischil Yep, added a link which explains 5.1.1.3.

That default value of 1 for macros defined by the -D option is historically true for Unix and is defined by POSIX for the c99 (previously c89 and cc) command. (I haven't checked the 2024 version yet, but suspect c99 has been replaced.)
